# Can't scroll/Drag the page Up and down by clicking on carousel section

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to use this carousel 
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/

But without using bottom part, I am only using thumb section to show movie posters.

Everything works fine, but When i open my page on mobile, I can't scroll the page up and down by clicking on carousel image.

Please find the code files from this link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzUuSGoEEtDxWVRRT0dWY2J4V0E/view?usp=sharing

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you can only scroll horizontal or vertical for the slider on the mobile and the page is scrolling nicely unless you describe the device screen size that is giving you issues